# R - tmap how to add datasets

Tags: r, geospatial, tmap

I'm new in spatial graphics. I have to present the tmap package for an exam at university. So I was wondering is there a way to add general graphics such as those in the preloaded "World", "Rivers", "Land"... datasets? which are basically "ready to use". Maybe from a repository i don't know of... I tried to look up online and on stack but couldn't find anything useful. 
I tried to use some .shp file downloaded online and load it as: 
`fvg <- readOGR("./FVG/CRN25000ED2_066_AREA.shp", layer = "CRN25000ED2_066_AREA")`. 
But i always have problems with the projection and honestly that's not what i'm looking for. I'd like to have something more slick if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is too general.

As a starting point you can check a tutorial I gave last year in Uruguay, this tutorial includes a tmap section.

- [The whole tutorial](https://orlando-sabogal.github.io/SpatialAnalysis-MontevideoWorkshop2019/)
- [the tmap section](https://orlando-sabogal.github.io/SpatialAnalysis-MontevideoWorkshop2019/Notebooks/tmap-tutorial.nb.html)

hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a read asap. Meanwhile, may I ask you if there is a general database on the web for .shp files or you just find them with a google search?

Comment: if you are working in R you can use the [spData](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spData/index.html), if you need the shape file you can easily export them.